# Laravel registeration file upload

Tags: laravel, file

I want to add file upload to laravel's register.
 I used `php artisan make:auth` so laravel created a `register.blade.php` file along with the rest of the authentication scaffolding. My problem is that i already had a filehandler interface in which i handled all my files. In previous usage I added the interface as an argument to the function and it worked. Like so:

```
public function save(MyFileHandlerInterface $file_handler,Request $request,$id)
    {
        $user=Auth::user();
        Item::create(['title'=>$request->title,
                  'description'=>$request->description
          ]);
        $mypath=  $file_handler->storef($request->file('image'));
        Upload::create(['address' => $mypath]);
        return view('welcome');
}
```

But now i can not do that because the create method in laravel's `RegisterController`. Only excepts 1 argument which is the data returned. So i tried to implement the interface in  `RegisterController` class via adding the interface's storef function:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller implements MyFileHandlerInterface
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'image' =>'required|file'
        ]);
    }


    public function storef($file)
    {
      $mypath = $file->store('drive/photos');
      return $mypath;
    }


    protected function create (array $data)
    {

        $mypath=$this->storef($data['image']);
        $user=User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        Userpic::create(['address' => $mypath]);
        return $user;
    }
}
```

but i get this error : `Call to a member function store() on string`
So how can i get a file from the `$data` array instead of a string?!
here is my `register.blade.php`:

```
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="image" class="col-md-4 control-label">image</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control" name="image" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('image'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: you could do this after the user has been created in the `registered` method which receives the request and the user

Comment: yes i can,but what if i want to do it while registering?

Comment: what is the difference if you do it after `User::create` is called?  you also don't seem to be linking the User to the UserPic at the moment

Comment: can you elaborate more? forgive me for being a rookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this in the `registered` method that is called after the User is created in the system:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

protected $file_handler

public function __construct(MyFileHandlerInterface $file_handler)
{
    $this->middleware('guest');

    $this->file_handler = $file_handler;
}

/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $path  = $this->file_handler->storef($request->file('image'));

    Userpic::create([
        'address' => $path,
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Wow!!! that worked like gangbusters! Thanks you very much for your elegant solution ;)